# javascript execution is not in the right order

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-accordion

I'm trying to get my head arround a strange problem with Bootstrap accordion. I have nested accordion and I want to close them all then open the ones linked to the users request.

My problem is that if the accordion is open, my code only closes the accordion but doesn't open it after. When the accordion is close initially, all is ok.

I tried to put an alert between the close and the open but what I can see is that the alert launches **before** the closing of the accordion even though it's after in the code.

```
$("input").on("paste", function (e) {
    $("#CodeScan").focus();
    setTimeout(function () {
        var value= $('#CodeScan').val();
        var tr = $("#" + value)[0];
        $('.panel-collapse.in').collapse('hide'); //hides all
        $("#CodeScan").val("");
        $("#" + value).focus();
        //alert("test");
        var box= $("#" + value).parent().parent().parent().parent();
        var bill= box.parent().parent().parent().parent();
        bill.collapse('show');
        box.collapse('show');
    }, 100);
});
```

Comment: You need to use callback functions for this.

Comment: @PraveenKumar That isn't very helpful. In what way could they utilize callback functions here?

Comment: The open/close use animations which process over time, but return immediately, think of them as setTimeout()s.  So it starts the animation, but immediately continues with the next code.  You need to use a callback to be called when the animation completes.

Comment: More specifically you need to provide a callback for the `hidden.bs.collapse` event. The behavior you're seeing is described in [the documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-methods).

Comment: @MikeC On the other hand, someone who simply answers all questions in good faith, regardless of to what degree a particular question is 'covered' by existing basic textbooks on Javascript, is arguably a net social loss for SO, and perhaps society at large.

Comment: `.parent().parent().parent().parent();` <-- that could be written cleaner

Comment: @ZephyrPellerin I 100% agree with you there but there is a middle ground between spoon-feeding and "you should use callback functions." That gives the asker absolutely nothing to go off of. 4castle provided a good example of that middle ground.

Comment: @MikeC I agree with your sentiment at large, but I also feel like this technique of 'general pointers' was a common and *effective* pedagogical technique, even before the age of Wikipedia. I would also put it forward to you the question of how *you* best learn - by having someone tell you the answer or by your own work? Of course doing it yourself is just frustrating without a good hint, but I think 'use callbacks is probably adequate'.

Comment: @ZephyrPellerin I agree with what you said but I disagree with your conclusion. I do not think that "use callbacks" is adequate. If you went to your calculus professor with a problem you're struggling with and showed them your work so far then they just said "use derivatives" you'd be just as lost as before.

Comment: Can you two please discuss this somewhere else. Open a quick chat room if you want to talk about this further.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/by6wgr5h/1/

Comment: @MikeC Er... True...